# Server uptime checker?

Tags: linux, php, uptime

I want to monitor my server's uptime. Is there some free application or a really good paid service that offers this? Obviously, I can't write something that is hosted on the server whose uptime I am checking.

Comment: why can't you write something that is hosted on *your* server? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Pingdom](http://Pingdom.com)

It has a 30 day trail, and you don't need to install anything on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is find out if its up, write a script to ping the server every 10 min or so. If you want something that will actually check functionality (like delivering a web page) write a javascript snippet that will refresh your page every n minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to monitor the uptime, then I would write simple perl script. But then if you are ready to buy paid product, then I would suggest to go for OPManager.. comes with 30 day trial.

http://www.manageengine.com/network-monitoring/

I personally have used it, simple to configure and bang on monitoring.....

--Maneesh

Answer (score 0):

Can't write anything on a hosted server? Strange... well, to those who can...

I'm using itSentinel which can do what your attempting for either Linux or Windows. You can check out http://www.itsentinel.com/viewforum.php?f=28 and float your mouse over the INFO link... as of this writing the mouse-over shows that the server named itSentinel has been up for 113 days, 5hours, 14 minutes, 22 seconds. If the server stops responding the color of the box will turn red.

Answer (score 0):

You can write write something on the server that you want to check :-D

You can write a small script that checks a few popular sites like google, yahoo, msn, amazon (other highly redundant services) etc. and logs failed pings. Of course this will not give you a real-time notice when the server goes down, but you can log in and see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get free server health monitoring at [**Cloudkick**](https://www.cloudkick.com/) (one node).  For an extra free node, check out my superuser profile.

[image: Cloudkick]